# How to jump to the file and line of the grep -nr output?

Tags: grep

Let's say I run
`grep -nr . -e "This text was found"`

And get in the CLI:
`./subfolder/file.ext:10 This text was found`

i.e. it's the 10th line in the file "file.ext" in the folder "subfolder".

How can I use this identifier "./subfolder/file.ext:10" to output the line from this file? or switch to a path in a different folder?

e.g. I jump there and see in the CLI:

`$otherfolder/subfolder/file.ext:10 Another text here`

Comment: You want to derive a different path based on the path of the matched file, or you want an absolute path to the match that would work from anywhere in the filesystem?

Comment: I want to jump to the line like this "less +10 $otherpath/subfolder/file.ext"

Comment: Are you saying that you want to run `less` and jump to the line `less +10 ${otherpath}/subfolder/file.ext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Moved from the question to an answer</sup>

I came up with this solution. It's not elegant and short (and also assumes that only one occurrence is found, but could be expanded on this), but does the job.

```
res=$(grep -nr . -e 'This text was found')
num=$(echo $res | cut -d: -f2)            # extract the number
file=$(echo $res | cut -d: -f2)           # extract the filename
sed -n "${num}p" $file                    # jump to the found line in the found file
folder=$(echo $file | cut -d/ -f1)
subpath=$(echo $file | cut -d/ -f1-)
sed -n "${num}p" $otherfolder/$subpath    # jump to the same line and subfolder structure in the other folder
```

Comment: I don't grok the `sed` lines: I don't grok what is meant by "jump".